# Facebook Graph API require content for field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

Is there a way to send a request to the Graph API with a parameter, the makes the response only deliver objects which are containing a certain field? As the Graph API is poorly documented, I still have a little hope that this is possible, even if I could not find any info about it in the documentation.

Something like:

```
272013516319233/posts?fields=message,created_time,link,picture&require=message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. You need to do the filtering on your side